how to import a dashboard in powerpoint?
What are all the methods possible to export a Power BI dashboard and import it into PowerPoint?
I tried clicking on "Share" as I saw in a tutorial, but I encountered an issue where this message appears:

and i don't have an account.

You need to share it to the service, then to power point from the service, not via desktop. You need a PBI account to do this. You say you don't have an account, you can sign up for free.

Did you click Share as in the tutorial?
As you can see in the tutorial, Patrick has published his report to the PowerBI service (app.powerbi.com) . Once your pbix file has been published to the service -using that shiny publish button at the end of the home ribbon- then you can Share the report into Powerpoint, by

Going to your published report (clickety click the link available when published)
Click share, as in tutorial ;)
Click powerpoint

As Patrick says: Bam, there you go.
Another way is going to PowerPoint and

on the Insert ribbon,
clicking the PowerBI option.

This shows you what you published in the PowerBI service and thus is eligible for showing in PowerPoint.
